# Insert or update record in sql server

Tags: sql-server, date-range, insert-update, days

I want to count the total number of days In daterange

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts will help us help you. Why do you want to use a `WHILE`, which will be by far the worst solution? Also, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year, why are you still using it? It's long past time you started your upgrade process.

Comment: Are you not just after `DATEDIFF` here?

Comment: But you can with `MIN` and `MAX`, as you appear to want here.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
SELECT vehicle,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(movedOn), MAX(movedOn))
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY vehicle;
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a lot of assumptions here.

- If a car moves three days in a row, there will be three records
- You might have bad data where a car has multiple records on one day
- You know how to exclude weekends
- You have small volumes of data (this will NOT scale)
- You understand recursion
- You understand Common Table Expressions

I wrote / tested on SQL Server 2017. I *believe* this will run on any version 2005+, no warranty expressed or implied. :)

```
/*
create table dbo.movement
(
     Id         int identity    not null
    ,VehicleId  int             not null
    ,EventDate  date            not null
)
*/

/*
set nocount on
delete      dbo.movement
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (1, '2020-07-02')
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (1, '2020-07-02')
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (1, '2020-07-03') --expecting 29, even though 3 records
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (2, '2020-07-03')
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (2, '2020-07-04') --expecting 29
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (3, '2020-07-01') --expecting 30
--insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (4, '2020-07-01') --no data, vehicle 4 won't show on report
insert into dbo.movement ( vehicleId, eventDate ) values (5, '2020-07-31') --expecting 30
*/

declare @inclusiveStartDate date = '2020-07-01'
declare @exclusiveEndDate   date = '2020-08-01'

declare @inclusiveEndDate   date = dateadd(day, -1, @exclusiveEndDate)

;with dateRange as
(
    select      @inclusiveStartDate     realDate
    union all
    select      dateadd(day, 1, realDate)
    from        dateRange
    where       realDate < @inclusiveEndDate
)
,movement as
(
    select       EventDate
                ,VehicleId
    from        dbo.movement
    where       EventDate >= @inclusiveStartDate
    and         EventDate <= @inclusiveEndDate
    group by     EventDate
                ,VehicleId
)
,movementCount as
(
    select       vehicleId
                ,count(distinct EventDate)  daysMoved
    from        movement
    group by    VehicleId
)
,calculation as
(
    select       (select count(1) from dateRange)               as totalDays
                ,VehicleId
                ,(select count(1) from dateRange) - daysMoved   as  StationaryDays
    from        movementCount
)
select       VehicleId
            ,StationaryDays
from        calculation
order by    VehicleId
```

Enjoy!